# How do I auto-display length in Table View?

Tags: swift

I can't determine the length of Cell TableView automatically

in Swift ,UIKit

I tried all the ways
Either it gives me a fixed length or the values in the Cell tableview are not shown

These are Table View codes

```
extension DetilesVC : UITableViewDelegate , UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrQ.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellDetiles
    
    let date = arrQ[indexPath.row]
    cell.arrQR = date
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}   
}
```

If I don't put this value here like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 900
}
```

Table View shouts like this

[image]

My Cell TableView

```
var arrQR : QRModel? {
    didSet {
        SetupQR()
        
    }
    
}
func SetupQR () {
    qusLabel.text = arrQR?.sub
    detailLabel.text = arrQR?.detiles
            }
```

Comment: Try to set the tableView `delegate` in `viewDidLoad` you will able to see the values.

Comment: Yes, they are all there before

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAt` put following code to show values in cells -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CellDetiles

let date = arrQ[indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel?.text = date
return cell
```

}

Comment: There is no problem here the data call is correct

Comment: Are you able to see the data in `tableViewCell` ?

Comment: Yes, right, no problem .. I have updated the question ... I retrieve data from firebase, there is no problem with the data